# Adding an object to a [String: [[String]]] dictionary

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift, append

I have a dictionary:

```
var dictionary: [String: [[String]]] = [
    "Janvier": [ ["", ""] ],
    "Février": [ ["", ""] ],
    "Mars": [ ["", ""] ],
    "Avril": [ ["", ""] ],
    "Mai": [ ["", ""] ],
    "Juin": [ ["", ""] ],
    "Juillet": [ ["", ""] ],
    "Août": [ ["", ""] ],
    "Septembre": [ ["", ""] ],
    "Octobre": [ ["", ""] ],
    "Novembre": [ ["", ""] ],
    "Décembre": [ ["", ""] ]
]
```

How can i add an other String array after ["", ""] like ["62", "2014-01-24"] ? There is no function like append so i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionary["Janvier"]?.append(["62", "2014-01-24"])
```

or

```
dictionary["Janvier"]!.append(["62", "2014-01-24"])
```

The difference is that the first variant does nothing if the dictionary has no
value for the key "Janvier", and the second variant aborts with an exception in that
case.

See also "Accessing Subscripts of Optional Type" in ["Optional Chaining"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_368)
in the Swift documentation.

Comment: Thanks the problem was that i didn't put the ? or !

Answer (score 0):

It *does* have an append method, but you need to unwrap the optional result of subscripting before you can use it:

```
dictionary["Mars"]?.append(["62", "2014-01-24"])
```